# How can I redesign a high-frequency, high-voltage power supply causing EMI around the home?

Tags: circuit-design, high-voltage, emc

How can I redesign a high frequency, high voltage, power supply causing EMI around the home?

I've been messing around with electronics for some time, and while I have briefly produced an arc or two, my setup hasn't been something I can just plug-n-play. This time around it isn't much different, but I want to keep this setup assembled as there have been brief occasions having high voltage would have been helpful.

The fear/problem I'm having is the high frequency (around 100 kHz) of the arc is interfering with, and in one case ruining, electronics nearby. Sometimes my monitor flashes, my mouse stops working, my T12 soldering iron freezes and occasionally the display on my power supply reads numbers not yet discovered (it is weird).

The worst was my DSO shell oscilloscope even when it was not in any way electrically connected to this circuit (just in the general vicinity of the arc); it is now constantly and permanently reading a maximum voltage. It is broken, which isn't too big of a deal considering that they cost like 30 bucks, but I don't want this to happen again so.

I work on electronics in my room, so I can't exactly cover everything in tin foil.  What can I do to my circuit that could stop it from interfering?

I've tried grounding the secondary and primary of this CRTV transformer and that may have helped, but it didn't fix it.

I don't know what to do. I may have reached the limits of doing electronics in my room, but I want to see what others would do because Google is pretty bad at returning helpful results once you enter "high voltage" as a search term.

Here is the circuit in question:

[image: schematic]

Comment: People may not be able to help much, even with a circuit. High voltage discharges tend to produce EMP (electromagnetic pulse), with fast risetimes, that easily travel through the air and couple into nearby wires, wreaking havoc on attached equipment. The easiest solution is the proverbial: "Doctor, it hurts when I do [this]!" "Then stop doing it!"

Comment: Please post a schematic and PCB layout.

Comment: lil matt19 - Hi, On Stack Exchange, when new information is needed in a question (or answer) that post should be edited - not deleted and reposted. Therefore this original question has been undeleted; the new schematic has been copied from your reposted question into this original one; and the reposted question (which was the same except the added schematic) has been deleted. Please don't "delete & repost" again. || This updated question is now in the queue for site members to review, to see if they believe it has enough detail to be reopened. || Please review the site [tour] & [help]. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You have designed a powerful source of wideband electromagnetic interference and the only way to tame it easily is to put the whole thing in a metal screened Faraday cage. The size of holes in the screen needs to be 1mm or slightly less. So, a rather fine copper mesh.

I'm basing this recommendation on the fact that even rather small arcs - like a powerful universal motor's commutator arcing - can easily wreck 5GHz ISM band WiFi. So you'd want screening that goes 2-3x higher in frequency than what's needed for a microwave oven door that only needs to be effective up to 2.4GHz.

Otherwise, you’d need to design active arc current slew rate control networks, and that’s not easy without proper instrumentation. You’d need to measure high voltages and fast changing currents with a wideband oscilloscope. That gets expensive really quickly if you don’t have the ability to design your own instrumentation (wideband HV probe, for example).

If you don’t plan on making a Faraday cage, then you should immediately stop using your circuit as it’s probably heard by radio receivers for several blocks around, and you may be interfering with professional communications. The level at which you transmit makes your device an intentional, unlicensed wideband transmitter and is not legal to operate.

You’d probably be less likely to cause trouble doing this work in a rural environment “in the middle of nowhere”. But rural areas are also more likely to depend on broadcast AM radio and your device will cause much trouble on broadcast band. So I’m afraid there is no easy way to just keep doing what you’re doing. A Faraday cage with no wires passing through it, ie. internally powered from battery/power bank, is the only simple solution that is within your level of knowledge at the moment (this of course will change as you learn, but we’re dealing with it right now).

Comment: @lilmatt19, pay very close attention to this answer. It is with no judgment in my heart when I say that you've built a radio jammer, and continuing to use it now that you know what you've done can get you in a heap of trouble. Law enforcement agencies and the FCC sometimes walk about with the detectors they need to find these things and possibly prosecute the owner. Don't freak out or beat yourself up too bad. Just do what Kuba says here. It may also be time to learn about radio frequency chokes and filters so you can apply power through the Faraday cage someday soon.

Comment: @lilmatt19 second this remark. If the thing you made is powerful enough to cause your gear to fail, it can easily do the same to someone in (say) an adjacent apartment. Causing nuisance is a best case scenario here. Causing problems which inadvertently lead to some kind of much worse accident is a distinct possibility. You need to dismantle this thing and leave it dismantled.

Comment: I would also not seriously entertain thoughts of enclosing this thing in a cage, as you presumably have no real way of knowing how effective the cage is. It's also possible (assuming that this is mains powered) that it is conducting inerference out via the supply wiring.

Answer (score 3):

A high voltage arc will emit a lot of interference in any case, and there is not much that can be done about that without removing the arc.

But there is another source of interference in the flyback driving circuit.
The schematic in the question is missing a few basic elements that are used to reduce noise emitted:

- Decoupling capacitors for the power supply. When placed close to the transformer and MOSFET, these reduce the length of the high-current loop on the primary side. This in turn reduces the emissions from it.
- Common mode choke for the power supply input cable. This can either be a ferrite core that is clamped around the power cable, or a small coil/transformer installed on the PCB. This reduces the emission and propagation of high-frequency noise through the long power supply cabling.
- RC snubber for the flyback transformer. This dissipates high-frequency oscillations that result from the switching. 100 kHz itself is quite low frequency and doesn't couple easily from and to short cables, but the fast switching action has much higher frequency components also.

Overall this application is similar to plasma balls which are used for decoration. They emit enough noise to be heard on radio receivers, but do not cause damage to nearby equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The only certain way to stop this thing from causing nuisance or worse to you and others is to switch it off and leave it off.